# udev symlink doesn't point to /dev file

Tags: 16.04, tty, udev, symbolic-link, modem

I am trying to create a udev rule to make a symlink to a usb modem when I plug it in. I expected the link to point to /dev/ttyACM0, however when running ls -l I get the output:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          15 Feb 11 11:28 cellmodem0 -> bus/usb/001/007
```

Here is the rule I have made:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1bc7", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0021", SYMLINK="cellmodem0", MODE="0666"
```

How do I make this point directly to ttyACM0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, SUBSYSTEM should equal "tty". This way it will map it to the tty file.

However, it is pointing to ttyACM3 instead of ACM0 because this devices makes multiple tty nodes, I will ask this question and link that answer here when it is answered.